# Do undeleted answers qualify for a bounty?

Tags: support, bounties, deleted-answers

On the question [Query multiple collections with different fields in solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313910/query-multiple-collections-with-different-fields-in-solr/19332939) the following sequence of events happened

1. The question got opened
2. I saw it and gave an answer
3. After the lunchbreak I saw a mistake in the answer and marked it as deleted, as it was wrong at that time
4. I started to correct the answer
5. Over that time the questioner started a bounty
6. After the correction I unmarked the delete and received several upvotes

Now the bounty starts to time out and I have read that an answer needs to be given (created) *after* the bounty has been started.

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

So I want to clarify that I understood this correctly and will not receive half of the bounty.

This feels odd as I and some others (the upvoters) think that I am right or at least on the right track.

Comment: As far as I can tell you're right. [The other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19361498/447356) is going to get half the bounty unless the bounty owner (who is also the OP) will manually give it to your answer, or accept it - which I believe also auto award the bounty. :)

Comment: While the argument "They were clearly not happy with existing answers so created a bounty" makes sense, an edited (or undeleted) answer is not really an "existing answer"

Comment: This is what makes me feel odd about it. The questioner had no real chance to view my answer before I marked it as deleted. Next time I would better give a new answer instead of undeleting? Does not feel better :)